# connect moleculer sevice to nestjs gateway through NATS server

Tags: microservices, nestjs, nats.io, moleculer

I am trying to create my first microservice server-side application. I created a gateway via Nestjs (a simple CRUD APIs) and then created a new service with this command:

```
moleculer init nano my-project
```

This service saves incoming data to local MongoDB

and then I created 4 actions for saving incoming data in local MongoDB

after that I install nats via snap store (Linux ubuntu):

```
sudo snap install nats
```

Now the gateway and service should communicate to each other through the NATS local server. The NATS documentation is confusing me because there are Subject-Based Messaging and Publish-Subscribe or Request-Reply and I do not know which should I use and how implement these connections in my Nestjs gateway

I want to call Moleculer actions from Nestjs gateway

This is installed package on Nestjs:

```
"dependencies": {
"@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
"@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
"class-transformer": "^0.4.0",
"class-validator": "^0.13.1",
"nats": "^2.2.0",
"nestjs-moleculer": "^1.0.5",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
"rimraf": "^3.0.2",
"rxjs": "^7.2.0"
 }
```

Comment: dear @CaRL , have you found any answer? I have this issue too

Answer (score 0):

Moleculer and Nestjs have different protocol so they can't communicate directly each other.
Maybe give a try to this module: https://github.com/jiangzhuo/nestjs-moleculer#readme

Comment: with this module, we can create moleculer service inside nestjs framework, right?

Comment: my main question is: 
Is there any way to call a moleculer action from nestjs gateway?